# How to locate a variable correctly in AT&T assembly?

Tags: assembly, ld, bootstrapping, att

I am practicing to write a bootstrap using assembly (in AT&T syntax, and gnu/gas). The small program is assembled and linked, then copied to the first sector of a virtual disk. BIOS will load it into `0000:7c00`, and here comes the problem. The `call hello` will be translated from `call 0010` to `call 7c10` during running. But the `movw $message, %as` doesn't get relocated. The `ax` is still `0026`, not `7c26`. The result is that I can't make the `Hello World` on the screen. Instead, some random data at `0000:0026` will be displayed on the screen.

How can I make it correct during booting? Should I change the asm source code using some directives? Or should I change my link script?

Thank you!

```
.text
.global     _start
.code16

_start:
movw    %cs, %ax
movw    %ax, %ds
movw    %ax, %es
call    hello
jmp     .

.org    0x10

hello:
movw    $message, %ax
movw    %ax, %bp
movw    $13, %cx
movw    $0x1301, %ax
movw    $0x000c, %bx
movb    $0, %dl
int     $0x10
ret

message:    
.ascii  "Hello, World!"

.org    0x01fe
.byte   0x55
.byte   0xaa
```

I use the following assemble and link scripts

```
as -o boot.o boot.s  
    //generate object code

ld -Ttext 0x0 -e _start -s -o boot.out boot.o  
    //relocate .text to 0x0
    //entry is _start

objcopy -O binary -j .text boot.out boot
    //copy .text section to boot

vboxmanage convertfromraw boot boot.vdi --format VDI
    //create vdi for virtual box
```

Comment: Use one org at the very beginning of your code. Choose what you want it to be 0, or 0x7c00. Use that same value when linking, if necessary. Modify the code appropriately so the segments and offsets have proper values prior the code accessing its data and calling functions.

Comment: Also, it will be much easier to just use NASM. You won't need ld or objcopy with it. It can assemble code into a binary directly (`-f bin` option).

Comment: Also, add the ss/sp initialization, so you are not running without the stack for sure

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Thank you for you advice, NASM would work. But in GAS (ATT Syntax), `.org` is defined to increase the counter, instead of specify the location as in NASM, (as far as I know). Actually, I tried to find something that likes NASM `.org` in GAS, but I didn't get anything.

Comment: @FrankKotler Thank you very much, your solution works very well. And I understand it now. Thank you!

Comment: @Serge Thank you for your advice. But since I am using the only code segment to reference my string variable, I think it's no need for me to specify `ss`. All of them will be in 0000:xxxx section.

Comment: You do use the stack: `call`, `int`, `ret`

Comment: You actually have some stack space after BIOS passed control to 0x7c00 but for consistency I would set the sp & ss

Comment: @Serge Oh, yes. You are right. I noticed in the VirtualBox Debug Console that the `sp` is set to 7c00, `ss` is 0000. But I don't know the reason. I am not quite understand the stack pointer at boot time.

Comment: The boot sector loading code set these values. By the specification all segment registers are cleared, sp is set to 7c00 and it jumps to 7c00. However, I would not rely on the assumption that every BIOS implementation or any other thing like RPL boot loader or whatever is following that specification. it is not too much instructions to load the ss and sp with known values, right? Why not to do it?

Comment: @Serge Yes, absolutely. I should not assume anything during boot. Specify anything explicitly makes everything in control. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the main problem is in the way you are compiling your code.

The correct steps to get your code working should be:

```
as boot.s -c -o boot.o
ld --oformat binary --Ttext 0x7C00 -o boot.bin boot.o
```

Please note, as others have said, that I'm passing the `--Ttext 0x7C00` parameter to `ld`, to force it relocating your code at that address.

As an additional suggestion, try to structure your code like this:

```
.text
.global     _start
.code16

_start:
jmp stage1_start

...

stage1_start:

<your bootloader here>
```

Note that this is compiant with how BIOS code looks at hard drives, since after 2 bytes (the length of the first jump instruction) you should place the Disk Description Table.

Additionally, you can refactor your last instructions in a more `as`-like syntax like this:

```
. = _start + 0x0200 - 2
.short 0x0AA55
```

Where the `.` variable is the location counter. Look at [this page](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Location-Counter.html) for further information on how this counter works (in the context of `ld`, not `as`).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great thanks to your detailed answer, and the links you provided! They are really helpful. Although I have already solved the problem by using -Ttext 0x7c00 option, your answer still provides good suggestions.