# Assembly get actual variable address?

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86

I am developing an OS in x86 assembly (using NASM) and ran into an annoying problem that I can not seem to solve. Ok so lets say I loaded my program into the address 0xFF (I did not load it there , just an example) and I had a variable that was at address 0xC in my executable. Now I used the org instruction and moved the variable into eax. Now the value of the variable will be 0xC instead of 0xFF + 0xC. Is there any way to get the actual value in memory or do I need to add the offset everytime?

Comment: Please show code and/or read http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdo12.html#section-12.1.3 , whichever you prefer first.

Comment: even though not gas, conceptually a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650291/how-to-locate-a-variable-correctly-in-att-assembly

Comment: The assembler should deal with offsets for you. And please show code.